# Displaying a modal instead of a echo message

Tags: php, html

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($res_username) > 0) {
    //echo "Sorry... Username already taken";
    echo "<script>$('#RegisterModal').modal('show')</script>";
}

<div id="RegisterModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            You have sucess registered!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the echo part, I want to display a modal showing a popup instead of a echo message.
Anybody help?

Comment: What is issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose your script in $(document).ready() so your show command executes only when the document is fully loaded to limit failure.

**Like:**

```
echo "
  <script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#RegisterModal').modal('show')
  });
  </script>";
```

Comment: Make sure your modal script is echoed. And make sure all required includes files are loaded.